# Could not load neutron_lbaas.drivers.haproxy.namespace_driver.HaproxyNSDriver

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm am beginner in openstack and I have install openstack ocata successfully.I using link below to install lbaas:
https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/networking-guide/config-lbaas.html

When i want to install lbaasv2 I encounter with error below:

```
openstack@ubuntu:~$ sudo neutron-lbaasv2-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/lbaas_agent.ini
Guru meditation now registers SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 by default for backward compatibility. SIGUSR1 will no longer be registered in a future release, so please use SIGUSR2 to generate reports.
2018-01-21 22:43:12.408 10772 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
2018-01-21 22:43:12.409 10772 INFO neutron.common.config [-] /usr/bin/neutron-lbaasv2-agent version 10.0.4
2018-01-21 22:43:12.411 10772 WARNING stevedore.named [req-6ebf45ef-7ff4-43c2-8c9a-d9b1f3acc839 - - - - -] Could not load neutron_lbaas.drivers.haproxy.namespace_driver.HaproxyNSDriver
^C2018-01-21 22:43:19.697 10772 INFO oslo_service.service [-] Caught SIGINT signal, instantaneous exiting
```

I enter commands in controller node.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That warning appears to be "cosmetic" - i.e. you can ignore it, and the agent should work OK - at least it does for me. Someone probably should file a bug on this. I may do that myself.